# Lenovo 320 - Improve battery life

Tags: laptop, battery-life

I am currently student and I wanted to buy budget laptop with relative strong performance.

1 year ago I bought Lenovo 320 ideapad 8GB ram, intel 8th gen. I used it only for programming, browsing internet, but on full battery he can work about ~1.5h to ~2.5h. When I am on my faculty, I need to have at least 4 hours to making notes in tex and other stuff and don't worry that on each break between lectures I need to find socket.

I am asking you, how can I improve battery life? Is there any option to replace my battery with another one to have 2x more capacity?

I don't know if it matters but I use system Xubuntu.

Comment: An external battery might be able to help you. How much are you willing to spend on a solution? Exactly how long do you need your laptop to last?

Comment: @Cfinley as I said, at least 4 hours but the more, the better (5h will be totally fine). But to have external battery I should have this still connected to laptop. I was thinking about big power bank which will be located in my backpack but I am not sure about that solution. I am able to spend something about 80$ on this solution

Answer (score 1):

- you may replace battery pack
- you may replace all accums in battery pack, may be it's lion 18650 3.7v 3000 - 3400mah - 9000mah. ~$3 for one.
- you may make a power bank 20-40-60Wah with 18650 elements and DC-DC converter (20V, 5A)